# how to store MinimalModbus debug response in a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, modbus, minimalmodbus

```
import serial
import minimalmodbus
import time

instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM8', 127, debug=True)
instrument.serial.port
instrument.serial.baudrate = 19200
instrument.serial.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
instrument.serial.bytesize = 8
instrument.serial.stopbits = 1
instrument.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU
instrument.serial.timeout = 0.300

b = instrument._communicate(b'\x7F\x66\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00', 64)

print(b)

instrument.serial.close()
```

On the terminal, I get the following:

```
MinimalModbus debug mode. Create serial port COM8
MinimalModbus debug mode. Will write to instrument (expecting 64 bytes back): 7F 66 01 00 02 00 00 00 01 00 (10 bytes)
MinimalModbus debug mode. Clearing serial buffers for port COM8
MinimalModbus debug mode. No sleep required before write. Time since previous read: 1222683890.00 ms, minimum silent period: 2.01 ms.
MinimalModbus debug mode. Response from instrument: 7F 66 01 00 4C 00 00 00 44 54 01 00 20 00 44 54 CB 74 14 43 AD B2 15 43 00 00 FA 44 00 94 9E 41 88 6D 08 00 88 6D 08 00 00 00 00 00 1A AB C3 40 45 A5 70 42 54 60 99 45 CF C4 03 00 00 00 00 00 (64 bytes), roundtrip time: 0.0 ms. Timeout for 
reading: 300.0 ms.

b'\x7ff\x01\x00L\x00\x00\x00DT\x01\x00 \x00DT\xcbt\x14C\xad\xb2\x15C\x00\x00\xfaD\x00\x94\x9eA\x88m\x08\x00\x88m\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1a\xab\xc3@E\xa5pBT`\x99E\xcf\xc4\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

When printing b, the data is not the same as the Response from instrument data. I assume it was distorted by some noise. Only the raw data is being stored in b. How can I get the actual data just like the response from instrument stored in variable b?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume it was distorted by some noise.

No - it's just the way you are outputting it; if you don't provide it with a format [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) outputs the "formal string representation" (see [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)). i.e. `7f` is unprintable so output `\7f`, `66` = `f` so output `f`, `01` is unprintable so output `\01` etc.

This can be demonstrated with:

```py
sampleBytes = bytes(bytearray.fromhex('7F 66 01 00 4C 00 00 00 44 54 01 00 20 00 44 54 CB 74 14 43 AD B2 15 43 00 00 FA 44 00 94 9E 41 88 6D 08 00 88 6D 08 00 00 00 00 00 1A AB C3 40 45 A5 70 42 54 60 99 45 CF C4 03 00 00 00 00 00'))
print(sampleBytes)
print(" ".join([f"{x:02X}" for x in sampleBytes]) + " ({} bytes)".format(
        len(sampleBytes)
    ))
```

which will generate:

```
b'\x7ff\x01\x00L\x00\x00\x00DT\x01\x00 \x00DT\xcbt\x14C\xad\xb2\x15C\x00\x00\xfaD\x00\x94\x9eA\x88m\x08\x00\x88m\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1a\xab\xc3@E\xa5pBT`\x99E\xcf\xc4\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
7F 66 01 00 4C 00 00 00 44 54 01 00 20 00 44 54 CB 74 14 43 AD B2 15 43 00 00 FA 44 00 94 9E 41 88 6D 08 00 88 6D 08 00 00 00 00 00 1A AB C3 40 45 A5 70 42 54 60 99 45 CF C4 03 00 00 00 00 00 (64 bytes)
```

So what you are seeing is the expected result and you already have the data you need. Note that the second `print` above uses the code MinimalModbus uses to output the "Response from instrument"; see [here](https://github.com/pyhys/minimalmodbus/blob/master/minimalmodbus.py#L1479) and [here](https://github.com/pyhys/minimalmodbus/blob/185afffd2d65b585f69bc5e3f640270d2bd27444/minimalmodbus.py#L2724).

Comment: Thank you. This helped me understand it a lot better. I was able to iterate thought the byte array and unpack the bytes that I want.